# How to Read a certificate from Usb Token for digital signing using java

Tags: java

For C# I am getting directly code, but for java I'm not able to find such code or API. Please help me regarding this.

I tried with `KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");`, 
but it returns server side installed certificate.

I want to read certificate from USB attached by client on his local machine.

Comment: If you want to read certificate from USB attached by client on his local machine then you have to use applet. Your code is running on server side so you will get server side certificate. Using Applet you will get client side certificate

Answer (score 0):

As per the [KeyStore JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html):

> Before a keystore can be accessed, it must be loaded.
>
> ```
> KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
>
> // get user password and file input stream
> char[] password = getPassword();
>
> try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("keyStoreName")) {
>     ks.load(fis, password);
> }
> ```